# Despite matching location and displaying the correct app, nginx changes url to base path

Tags: nginx

I have 2 webapps and a node/express app that run in my server. The base app `asdf` runs in the base location when a request is sent to `https://asdf.com`. There is also a secondary webapp called `help` that runs when you request `https://asdf.com/help`, and a proxy app (not really relevant) that responds to requests to `https://asdf.com/proxy`.

When I hit `https://asdf.com` or `https://asdf.com/proxy` everything works as expected and my url stays the same. However, when I hit `https://asdf.com/help` I get the `help` webapp running but my URL says `https://asdf.com` and navigation works as expected but if I refresh the site I get the `asdf` app instead as it should be.

I have the following nginx config file:

```
server {
  ssl on;
  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name asdf.com;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/asdf.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/asdf.com.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  root /var/www/asdf;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /help/index.html;
  }

  location /help {
    root /var/www/development/client;
  }

  location /proxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection 1;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
  add_header Referrer-Policy 'strict-origin';
}
```

How can I change it so that when I hit `https://asdf.com/help` my URL doesn't change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `nginx` is not changing the address bar, the help webapp is. If `nginx` had made the change, you would be redirected to the base app.

Comment: Thanks for this. You are right, I think. How can I prevent this in an angular 6 application?